# Controlled access and routing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I have a rails application and I want to manage access to the application in a controlled way.
The client user would have access to only certain views in the application, whereas the admin can access any page.
In future, I may also add some semi-admins who might have access to a subset of pages that were accessed by the admin.
I already have a login authentication but I want a better solution to control user access to certain pages in my application.

Comment: @Mark - 
I know how to use before_login and use basic login authentication.
What i want to do is :

Lets say i have a buyer, customer and a vendor model.
My admin can see change all the models through views created by scaffolds.
My semi-admin can access only customer model.
My client user can see only his user model and the data i show him.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears you have the basics of authentication down, but just need a role-based authorization solution.  You might want to take a look at [CanCan](http://github.com/ryanb/cancan), it works well with most authentication packages.  There is a good [railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/192-authorization-with-cancan) on how to use it.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

use [before_filter](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Filters/ClassMethods.html#M000316)

users_controller.rb

```
  class UsersController < ApplicationController
    before_filter :login_required, :except=>[:show]
    before_filter :required_admin, :only=>[:all_users]

    def show

    end

    def all_users

    end

    def edit

    end

  end
```

application_controller.rb

```
  class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

    def current_user
       session[:user]
    end

    def login_required
      if current_user
        return true
      else
        flash[:notice]='Please login to continue.'
        redirect_to :controller => "logins"
      end
    end

    def required_admin
      if current_user && current_user.is_admin?  #check here if current user is admin or not
        return true
      else
        flash[:notice]='Please login as admin.'
        redirect_to :controller => "logins"
      end
    end
  end
```

1. Show method can see anyone with & without login
2. only admin can see all_users method
3. edit method can see any login user (i.e user admin)

Comment: This i have done already. What i want is say i have a buyer, customer and a vendor model.
My admin can see change all the models through views created by scaffolds.
My semi-admin can access only customer model.
My client user can see only his user model and the data i show him.

Comment: Views aren't one-to-one with models, so this depends on how you're presenting your app. If you want, you could have, say, a `show` view where there is a conditional branch inside that redirects to either `show_admin` or `show_user` depending on who is viewing it.